# "error" or "fail" for $.post Ajax call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to trigger a [Bootstrap Growl](http://bootstrap-growl.remabledesigns.com/) message if `$.post` call fails. How I know if it fails? Because backend part (PHP script) returns this JSON:

```
{
   "success":false,
   "errors":{
      "usuario":{
         "captcha":[
            "The captcha is not valid."
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

So I did this in jQuery:

```
$.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
    // ... Process the result ...
}, 'json').fail(function(result) {

    console.log("fail");

    $.growl({
        icon: "fa fa-paw",
        title: "<strong>Error en datos</strong>",
        message: "Los siguientes errores ocurrieron",
        type: "danger",
        allow_dismiss: true,
        animate: {
            enter: 'animated bounceInDown',
            exit: 'animated bounceOutUp'
        }
    });
});
```

But none the message or the `console.log()` works so I don't know if the right is `.fail()` or `.error()` or all the time is success and then I need to verify if `success` at JSON comes with `FALSE` which means some error.

As a second little question, how I move inside the JSON looking for errors strings for show them as LI inside the `message` at Growl element?

Comment: Instead of using a .fail callback, can't you just check to see if the JSON data returned has `success: false`, and if it does, serve the growl message. 

`$.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) { if(result.success === false) { // growl here } }`

Comment: @MitulP91 this is exactly what I said here `or all the time is success and then I need to verify if success at JSON comes with FALSE which means some error.`

Comment: The `fail/error` is called if the ajax request is failed like returns a http status like 5xx or 4xx, another possibility is an abort call on the request or a parsing error of the response

Comment: If you want your code to handle this as a fail and you control the server-side code, have it give the response a status code of 500.  Then your $.post will know it was a failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fail clause will be triggered if the response contains an http error, for example, a 400 or a 500. If the http response is 200 - ok, then you won't get a failure.

Comment: Exactly - just because your response is for a failure doesn't mean it registers as a "fail" condition.  It's all about the status code that is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {

    //code for success
    if (result.success) {
        //TODO
    }

    //code for failure
    if (!result.success) {
        console.log("fail");

        $.growl({
            icon: "fa fa-paw",
            title: "<strong>Error en datos</strong>",
            message: "Los siguientes errores ocurrieron",
            type: "danger",
            allow_dismiss: true,
            animate: {
                enter: 'animated bounceInDown',
                exit: 'animated bounceOutUp'
            }
        });
    }//if failed
},
'json');
```

Comment: Your code works and it what I was trying to do just got that doubt and ask here, now any advice in how to get the values from `errors` separately in order to show them as LI?

Comment: access your error information through result.errors

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing a captcha failure and an ajax call failure as the same thing, if I am interpreting your question correctly, that is.

The ajax call itself is succeeding, which is why you see none of the ajax failure output. The JSON returned by the SUCCESSFUL call contains information(success:"false") stating that the captcha entry failed to pass it's test. Does that make sense?

You will need to take the success attribute in the result JSON and apply appropriate actions depending on it being a success true or false.